# Como tomar los valores que se desean con operadores logicos

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Estoy tratando de obviar uno de los pasos que tengo en este proyecto son 4 perlas o botones, cada perla le pertence a un current_step en este caso, son las siguientes
[9,10,11,12], yo deseo obviar el numero 10 ya que no se estara utilizando por los momentos.

he declarado en mi modelo un metodo con un callback after_find de esta manera

```
after_find :juridico_step

    def juridico_step
       if self.current_step == 10
          self.update_column(:current_step, self.current_step + 1)
    end
```

Cuando sea current_step 10, quiero que actualice y sume 1 para que salte ese paso, el problema es que tambien quiero devolverme al paso 9 pero no me permite porque siempre se va a cumplir esa condicion.

Espero puedan ayudarme.

Comment: ¿y cual es la condición para devolverse a 9?

Comment: Esa es mi duda, no se como declarar la condicion para devolverme :/

Comment: Reformulando la pregunta entonces, ¿por qué quieres devolverte a 9?

Comment: porque el usuario puede dar anterior o siguiente, por los momentos el step 10 no se esta usando por lo que solo quiero que pase de 9 a 11 y viceversa, quiero que siempre se excluya el step 10.

Comment: Ok entonces, por ejemplo, al usuario se le muestra el paso 9, elige el 10, entonces tendría que ser guardado el 11? y viceversa, si está en el 11, elige el 10, entonces se guarda el 9?

Comment: Exactamente, si el usuario se encuentra en el paso 9 y da siguiente sera redirigido al step 11 y si da anterior al step 9

Answer (score 0):

No se si `after_find` sea el mejor callback a elegir para esta tarea, porque este se ejecuta cuando buscas un registro y usarlo da a entender que ya existe guardado en tu BD un registro con el paso 10 y no sabrías si tienes que cambiarlo a 9 o a 11.

De cualquier forma, creo que deberías usar `before_save` para que el chequeo se haga antes de cada vez que el registro vaya a ser creado o actualizado. Tampoco debería ser necesario `update_column`, porque `juridico_step` será llamado antes de que el registro sea escrito. Algo como esto podría servirte:

```
before_save :juridico_step

def juridico_step
  return if current_step != 10

  self.current_step = 11 if current_step_was == 9
  self.current_step = 9 if current_step_was == 11
end
```

Comment: No me funciono :( de igual manera gracias por responder seguire analizando el problema.

Comment: @ArturoGabriel pero entonces da mas informacion de que no te funcionó. Que te muestra el log completo de la petición al actualizar tu registro? hay la posibilidad que haya otros callbacks involucrados en tu modelo? cual es el codigo involucrado a nivel de controlador-modelo?

Comment: El metodo solo se esta ejecutando cuando tiene como callback after_find, por ejemplo como lo tenia antes que le sumaba 1 cuando era == 10 esta funcionando correcto pero que condicion deberia colocar tambien para que se regrese ignorando el paso 10, por ejemplo este proceso tiene como 16 pasos, el usuario va llenando sus datos y da siguiente, hasta que llega al paso 9 llena los campos y da siguiente, ahi deberia redirigirme al step 11, pero supongamos que me equivoque y decido editar el paso 9, pues deberia ser capaz de dar "anterior" y saltar nuevamente el paso 10.